# Qt 4.8 Why my QIODevice not output a text in this code?

Tags: qt, qiodevice

If used QTextStream console(stdout) - all work just fine, but if I wrote custom IODevice, after qInstallMsgHandler() no text in console

main.cpp
    #include "remoteconsole.h"

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QTimer>

QTextStream *out;

void logOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
    QString debugdate = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    *out << debugdate << " " << type << msg << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    RemoteConsole * remote = new RemoteConsole(&a);
    QTextStream console((QIODevice *)remote);
    out = &console;
    qDebug() << "start qInstallMsgHandler";
    qInstallMsgHandler(logOutput);
    qDebug() << "end qInstallMsgHandler"<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        qDebug() << i<<endl;
    }

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
    a.connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    timer->start(5000);

    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

my IODevice implementation in file remoteconsole.h .cpp

```
#ifndef REMOTECONSOLE_H
#define REMOTECONSOLE_H

#include <QIODevice>
#include <QDebug>

class RemoteConsole: public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RemoteConsole(QObject *parent);
    ~RemoteConsole();
private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(RemoteConsole)
protected:
     qint64 readData(char* data, qint64 maxSize);
     qint64 writeData(const char* data, qint64 maxSize);
};



#endif // REMOTECONSOLE_H

#include "remoteconsole.h"

RemoteConsole::RemoteConsole(QObject* parent=0) :
    QIODevice(parent)
{

}

RemoteConsole::~RemoteConsole(){}

qint64 RemoteConsole::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen){
    qDebug() << data <<endl;
    return maxlen;
}

qint64 RemoteConsole::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len){
    printf("writeData");
    qDebug() << data <<endl;
    return len;
}
```

In future I want to expand this code with QTCPServer, that send debug outputs to client connected to the device by telnet or nc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any text in console after `qInstallMsgHandler` call because you send all debug data into your `RemoteConsole` object.

Also you've got some other problems in your code.

1. You should call `QIODevice::open` before you can operate on that device.
2. In the `RemoteConsole::writeData` function you will have an infinite loop because you use `qDebug()` there. `qDebug()` will call `logOutput` which will call `RemoteConsole::writeData` again.